# How to update redis password and connection on live in Spring data redis?

Tags: spring-data-redis

I want to update the redistemplate to connect redis using new password by the following code. but I get error. Could someone kindly help? Thanks!

```
 LettuceConnectionFactory factory = (LettuceConnectionFactory) redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory();
 factory.getSentinelConfiguration().setPassword(newPassword);
 factory.initConnection();
```

Error:
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to 10.32.216.24:6379
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getNativeConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1112) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.15.RELEASE.jar:2.1.15.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1091) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.15.RELEASE.jar:2.1.15.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getSharedConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:872) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.15.RELEASE.jar:2.1.15.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.initConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:413) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.15.RELEASE.jar:2.1.15.RELEASE]
        at com.xxx.oss.ntcapp.annotation.ResetRedisAspect.resetRedisPassword(ResetRedisAspect.java:62) ~[ntcapp-common-20.0.4.27.jar:?]
        at com.xxx.oss.ntcapp.annotation.ResetRedisAspect.resetRedisConnectionFactory(ResetRedisAspect.java:51) ~[ntcapp-common-20.0.4.27.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor167.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        at com.xxx.oss.ntcapp.common.utils.RedisTemplateUtil$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3090c68.listSize() ~[ntcapp-common-20.0.4.27.jar:?]
        at com.xxx.oss.ntcapp.config.SchedulerConfig.handleFmNotification(SchedulerConfig.java:156) ~[ntcapp-starter-20.0.4.27.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor178.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_242]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [?:1.8.0_242]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_242]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [?:1.8.0_242]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_242]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_242]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_242]
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to 10.32.216.24:6379
        at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:78) ~[lettuce-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:56) ~[lettuce-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.getConnection(AbstractRedisClient.java:235) ~[lettuce-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:204) ~[lettuce-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.lambda$getConnection$1(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:113) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.15.RELEASE.jar:2.1.15.RELEASE]
        at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.getConnection(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:113) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.15.RELEASE.jar:2.1.15.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getNativeConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1110) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.15.RELEASE.jar:2.1.15.RELEASE]
        ... 29 more
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR invalid password
        at io.lettuce.core.ExceptionFactory.createExecutionException(ExceptionFactory.java:135) ~[lettuce-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at io.lettuce.core.ExceptionFactory.createExecutionException(ExceptionFactory.java:108) ~[lettuce-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand.completeResult(AsyncCommand.java:120) ~[lettuce-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand.complete(AsyncCommand.java:111) ~[lettuce-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandWrapper.complete(CommandWrapper.java:59) ~[lettuce-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.complete(CommandHandler.java:646) ~[lettuce-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:604) ~[lettuce-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.channelRead(CommandHandler.java:556) ~[lettuce-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        ... 1 more

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by using the following code:

```
LettuceConnectionFactory factory = (LettuceConnectionFactory) redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory();

if (null != factory.getSentinelConfiguration()) {
    factory.getSentinelConfiguration().setPassword(newPassword);
}

factory.afterPropertiesSet();
factory.initConnection();
factory.validateConnection();
```